# Box2d gravity not being applied correctly in Box2d c#

Tags: c#, .net, box2d

So basically, when I set my gravity to 0, everything sits there. This is correct, but when I set the gravity to anything other than 0, everything falls at the same speed no matter what value I pass into the gravity. Here is some sample code to demonstrate this using Box2d and Raylib:

```
    //Create world
    static World world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0));

    //Create bodies
    static Body groundBody;
    static Body playerBody;

    //Set values
    static int deltaTime = 8; //about 120fps

    static int velocityIterations = 6;
    static int positionIterations = 2;

    public static void StartGameLoop()
    {
        Raylib.InitWindow(1000, 500, "hello world");

        OnStart();
        while(!Raylib.WindowShouldClose())
        {
            Update(); //Handles updating stuff
            Draw();   //Handles drawing stuff
            Thread.Sleep(deltaTime); //Keeps a (relatively) constant fps going
        }
    }

    static void OnStart()
    {
        //Set world gravity
        world.SetGravity(new Vector2(0, 10));

        //Create ground
        BodyDef groundDef = new BodyDef();
        groundDef.position = new Vector2(0, Raylib.GetScreenHeight() - 20);
        groundBody = world.CreateBody(groundDef);

        PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();
        groundBox.SetAsBox(Raylib.GetScreenWidth(), 10);
        groundBody.CreateFixture(groundBox);

        //Create the player
        BodyDef playerDef = new BodyDef();
        playerDef.type = BodyType.Dynamic;
        playerDef.position = new Vector2(Raylib.GetScreenWidth() / 2, 200);
        playerBody = world.CreateBody(playerDef);

        PolygonShape playerBox = new PolygonShape();
        playerBox.SetAsBox(25, 25);

        FixtureDef playerFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        playerFixtureDef.shape = playerBox;
        playerFixtureDef.density = 1;
        playerFixtureDef.friction = .3f;
        playerBody.CreateFixture(playerFixtureDef);
    }

    static async Task Draw()
    {
        Raylib.BeginDrawing();
        Raylib.ClearBackground(Raylib_cs.Color.BLACK);

        //Draw player
        Raylib.DrawRectangle((int)playerBody.Position.X - 25, (int)playerBody.Position.Y - 25,
            50, 50, Raylib_cs.Color.GREEN);

        //Draw ground
        Raylib.DrawRectangle((int)groundBody.Position.X - Raylib.GetScreenWidth() / 2, 
            (int)groundBody.Position.Y - 10, Raylib.GetScreenWidth() * 2, 20, Raylib_cs.Color.RED);

        await Task.Delay(0);
        Raylib.EndDrawing();
    }

    static void Update()
    {
        world.Step(deltaTime, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
    }
```

Thanks in advance to anybody that helps me

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the first parameter of the method Step() is measured in seconds, not milliseconds. If you want to have 120 fps, set 1f/120f as the first parameter of Step(). Probably your problem is too long step time